# Discord.py on_member_join not working, no error message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot with the Discord.py library. The commands with the @client.command() decorator work fine for me, but none of the event ones that I tried work.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(ChannelId) #I did define channel Id in my code
    await channel.send("someone has joined")

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    print("Someone has left")
```

I would expect this to output to the terminal or in the channel id I put in, but nothing appears, not even an error message.

*I used client. for all functions.
*I am doing this on mac.

Im not quite sure why its working, I do not get any error messages, and I cant seem to find anyone else with this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [my function on\_member\_join(member) is never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64425548/my-function-on-member-joinmember-is-never-called)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With version >1.5.0 you can do something like this:

```
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send("Welcome!")
```

You also need to enable intents in the developer portal in https://discord.com/developers/applications. Bot > Bot > Presence & Server Members Intents > Toggle On

Comment: Note that you *also* need to enable it in the dev portal. You need to go to [developer portal --> applications](https://discord.com/developers/applications) (select your bot) and in the settings, navigate to 'Bot'. Scroll down, and you'll see Member Intents, which you can enable.

Answer (score 1):

```
import discord
intents = discord.Intents.all()
discord.member = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="[",intents = intents)
```

and you need to go to developer portal --> applications(select your bot)
and under the setting have a bot. Click it under the page has PRESENCE INTENT and SERVER MEMBERS INTENT you need to open it. That will be working.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using discord.py v1.5.0, see the docs for [Gateway Intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html)