# on_member_join(member) is never called in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a discord bot with discord.py on python 3.8.6.

My other functions, such as `on_ready` and other commands, work. However, `on_member_join` is never called when a member joins.

```
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix =".")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('logged on salaud')

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print("test")

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Why is `on_member_join` not being called, and how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`discord.py` **v1.5**  introduces **intents**

> An intent basically allows a bot to subscribe into specific buckets of events.

In order to be able to get server data you need to:

- Enable Server Member intents in your [application](http://discord.com/developers/applications)
  [image]
- And Implement `discord.Intents` at the beginning of your code.

```
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.all()


bot = discord.Client(intents=intents)

# or 

from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".", intents=intents)
```

For more information, read about [Intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#what-intents-are-needed) | [*documentation*](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents)