# def on_member_join not working discord.py 1.17.3

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a discord bot with python. However, the on_message_join
function doesn't seem to work.
This is my code:

```
import discord
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print("test")
client.run('token')
```

When a member joins it doesn't print "test". Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [my function on\_member\_join(member) is never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64425548/my-function-on-member-joinmember-is-never-called)

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Yes, this worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable intents in developer's portal and in client variable

```
client = commands.Bot(intents = discord.Intents.all())
```