# discord.py problems with on_member_join()

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

What am I doing wrong?

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f"{member} join")
    role_1 = member.guild.get_role(start_role_id)
    await member.add_roles(role_1)
```

I searched for answers on the forums for a long time and nothing helped.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [my function on\_member\_join(member) is never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64425548/my-function-on-member-joinmember-is-never-called)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you enable `intents` in [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)? while initializing bot add `intents=discord.Intents.all()`. Also I fixed your code.

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='', intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f"{member} join")
    role1 = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, id=role_id)
    await member.add_roles(role1)
```

Comment: Thank you, now "on_member_join()" works, but the role is not issued and this error is displayed: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'server'

Comment: Mb, replace member.server.roles with member.guild.roles

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='PREFIX_HERE',     
intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f"{member} has joined")
    my_role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=role_id)
    await member.add_roles(my_role)
```

Comment: NameError: name 'message' is not defined =(

Comment: @ИльяПростаков Try swap message for member? (member.guild.roles)