# Discord bot, The bot does not send messages about the arrival of a new member Python

Tags: python, discord.py

I am new to creating bots for Discord and I take codes from different examples and I write on replit.
I want the bot to send a welcome message to a new member of the server, but when I invite my 2nd account, it doesn't send anything. I have included Intentions

[Full code](https://github.com/jonoto2/disBot/blob/main/main.py)

```
import discord
from discord import Game
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio
from webserver import keep_alive
import os

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id=870695778593701939)
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title=f"Welcome {member.name}",
        description=f"Thanks for joining {member.guild.name}!")  # F-Strings!
    embed.set_thumbnail(
        url=member.avatar_url
    )  # Set the embed's thumbnail to the member's avatar image!
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

And that's all I'm writing on the phone and I don't understand how I can return this whole code and where, so sorry

Comment: You're redefining the client (as a bot?) with no intents.

Comment: Therfore, this should answer your question? [on\_member\_join(member) is never called in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64425548/on-member-joinmember-is-never-called-in-discord-py)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm guessing `I have included Intentions` means that you have added the intents in the bot constructor and the developers portal
so first
`channel = client.get_channel(channel_id=870695778593701939)`
`channel_id` is not the argument name its `id` and its a positional argument so you can just do `client.get_channel(channel_id_here)` would work, just replace `channel_id_here` with the channel id

second when your setting `url=member.avatar_url` in the `set_thumbnail` function it would raise an error if the member has no avatar so i would suggest you check if the user has a avatar, if they don't just give it `member.default_avatar_url`, but if your using discord.py 2.0 (master branch) then its ALOT easier with `member.display_avatar.url`
this is just a suggestion because `display_avatar` returns the users/members avatar if they have one or the default discord gives them so no errors are raised

Comment: I changed everything as you indicated but the bot still does not send messages when I join by invitation from the second account

Comment: ok now I see why it doesn't work, its because first you made the client a discord.Client with the intents, but then you override the client with a commands.Bot that doesn't have the intents

Comment: so you just removed the `client = discord.Client(intents=intents)` and make `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')` into `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)`

Comment: I don't understand where is my mistake

Comment: basically remove the `client = discord.Client(intents=intents)` line

Comment: and edit the `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')` line into

Comment: `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)`