# Discord bot on_member_join Is not working Can someone explaint

Tags: python, discord.py

[Discord welcome message isnt working can someone explain or help?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnh7g.png)

Comment: You code doesn't have a `member` parameter. It would actually do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

First change (message) to (member). Then;

1. Go to Discord Developer Portal and;

- Go to the application your bot is in.
- Turn Server Members Intent on. [image]

2. Add this to your code after your imports;

```py
#imports here

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
```

Then it should work.
Also this is a duplicate of [Discord.py on_member_join not working, no error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64147556/discord-py-on-member-join-not-working-no-error-message).

Answer (score -1):

The `discord.on_member_join` function has `"member"` as a parameter. Then you can use `member.send("Your message here")` to send an inbox to your user.

Official documentation [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_member_join#discord.on_member_join).

Comment: What do i replace though?

Comment: The only parameter you can have in discord.on_member_join is "member." Therefore, you can't pass a "message" into that function.