# How do i fix this autorole?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hey i have a problem im trying to make autorole when someone joins but i dont get whats worng

````
async def on_member_join(member):
   guild = client.get_guild(837586432003407872)
   role = guild.get_role(842049118917885973)   
   await member.add_roles(role)```
````

Comment: Is there an error or does it just not work? Have you enabled `intents.members`, which is necessary?

Comment: It just dont work and how can i check that intents.member is on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py on\_member\_join not working, no error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64147556/discord-py-on-member-join-not-working-no-error-message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem a while ago. Solution:

1. First enable SERVER MEMBERS INTENT in `Bot` tab on [discord developers](https://discord.com/developers/applications/) site. Picture:

[image]

2. add this code into your code:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="your prefix", intents=intents)
#put bot at the beggining if you are using bot as a variable
```

3. Enjoy working code