# Welcome message not being sent in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I made a new server and made a custom bot for it recently, but the welcome message doesn't really seem to work... It is also supposed to give a particular role to the member who joined but I removed that code and the current code still doesn't work.

Sadly, the command prompt gives no errors. I have no idea what to do now.

Here is the code -

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self, member):
        #GETTING THE GUILD, CHANNEL AND ROLE
        channel = self.client.get_channel(828481599057166356)
        name = member.name

        #CREATING THE WELCOME EMBED
        welcomeem = discord.Embed(title = f"Hey there {member.name}!", description = f"Welcome to {chanenl.guild.name}! Have a fun time here in TigerNinja's server!")
        welcomeem.add_field(name="1. Rules", value = f"{name}, before you start having fun here, make sure to check <#752474442650878002> and read all rules as they will come in handy in the server!", inline=False)
        welcomeem.add_field(name="2. Self-roles", value = f"{name}, be sure to check out <#776293478594379797> and get all roles you want!", inline=False)
        welcomeem.add_field(name="2. Help", value = f"{name}, need help with this bot then type `t.help`. If you need help relating to something else, contact the mods via dms, but don't ping them!!", inline=False)

        #SENDING THE PING, EMBDE AND ADDING ROLE
        await channel.send(f"Welcome, {member.mention}!")
        await channel.send(embed=welcomeem)
```

(I am using cogs btw)

Comment: Do you have member intents?

Comment: Yes I do have all intents enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up this command as bot event? Before adding such command you should add
`@bot.event` (or whatever name you gave to discord.Client in your code + .event, it might be useful to share more of your code, just be careful not to include your token or any private information).

For more info, look into this post, I believe it is the answer you are looking for:
[Discord.py on_member_join not working, no error message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64319222/15209678)

Comment: Yea I did... Lemme edit the code in the question make it proper again

Answer (score 0):

Following the dicord.py [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-send-a-message-to-a-specific-channel):

```
channel = guild.get_channel(828481599057166356)
```

should be:

```
channel = client.get_channel(828481599057166356)
```

**EDIT:**
I found something else:

```
welcomeem = discord.Embed(title = f"Hey there {member.name}!", description = f"Welcome to {chanenl.guild.name}! Have a fun time here in TigerNinja's server!")
```

you misspelled "channel" in {chanenl.guild.name}

Comment: I tried implementing this but nope, not a chance.

It shows no errors too. Plus I have all intents.

Comment: Thanks for finding that mistake but still it doesn't work! No errors either! I have NO idea why! I re-edited the code there. Please check again