# Discord.py auto role/welcome message

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to get it to give the members role to new members but it doesn't seem to work can anyone help?

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(ctx, member):
    if member.guild.name == "VRnerds":  # Server Name
        role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="members")
        await member.add_roles(role)
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Member Joined", description=f"{member.mention}, Welcome to {member.guild.name}. We hope that your time with us is a happy one!", color=0x9b26b9, font_size=200, timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow())

        embed.add_field(name="Please check out the Rules Channel!", value="Coming soon", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Latest announcements are made here!", value="Coming soon", inline=False)
        embed.set_footer(text="")

        await client.get_channel(938282805274771458).send(embed=embed)

    else:
        return
```

Comment: Did you get a specific error message?

Comment: no it just wont send a message or add a role when a new member joins

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py on\_member\_join not working, no error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64147556/discord-py-on-member-join-not-working-no-error-message)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly [on_member_join](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_join) doesn't take a `ctx` parameter so `member` isn't defined in your code right now.

Secondly (always was for me like this, guess it's for all) you can't do `await client.get_channel(C_ID).send()` as `client.get_channel` is no coroutine and so you can't use await on it.

(thirdly you don't need the `else: return` if you ain't got anything after it)

In the end your code then would look like this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if member.guild.name == "VRnerds":  # Server Name
        role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="members")
        await member.add_roles(role)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Member Joined", description=f"{member.mention}, Welcome to {member.guild.name}. We hope that your time with us is a happy one!", color=0x9b26b9, font_size=200, timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
        # you don't need the f before Strings with no variables or statements in it

        embed.add_field(name="Please check out the Rules Channel!", value="Coming soon", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Latest announcements are made here!", value="Coming soon", inline=False)
       embed.set_footer(text="")  # < You can remove this if there wasn't any content

        c = client.get_channel(938282805274771458)
        await c.send(embed=embed)
```

I'd also advice you to use `member.guild.get_role(ROLE_ID)` as you may change your name of the Role later and then this still works

Answer (score -1):

I think the mistake here is `name=members`. Change it to `id=roleid` with roleid being the integer state of the ID of the role you want to mention. You can do this in the DiscordUI by enabling developer mode and right clicking the role and clicking Copy ID.

Comment: Nope that doesn't work