# making a greetings bot for discord

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

so, I'm trying to do a bot that greets people when they join getting a greeting from a list and then randomizing it and mentioning them, but I can't get it to mention a user while also choosing a random greeting, what could I do?

```
import discord
import os
import random

client = discord.Client()

invites = ["has been invited by"]

username = client.get_user(id)

starter_greetings = [

  "hola como estas"
]

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('we have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  msg = message.content

  channel = client.get_channel(940394154972823593)

  if any(word in msg for word in invites):
    await channel.send(username + random.choice(starter_greetings))

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Comment: use `on_member_join`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, instead of checking for a message's content, you can check if a user joins the server via the [`on_member_join`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_member_join#discord.on_member_join) event, which runs whenever a user joins the server. You can send a message to a specific channel, and have your bot mention the user by using [`discord.Member.mention`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20member#discord.Member). Do have a look at the example below.

```py
starter_greetings = [
  "hola como estas",
  "welcome to the server",
  "enjoy your stay"
]

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    join_channel = member.guild.get_channel(YOUR_CHANNEL_ID) # get the channel of your choice
    await join_channel.send(f"{member.mention} {random.choice(starter_greetings)}")
    # send the member and a random option from starter_greetings list
```

[image: working example]

Comment: ok, so I added this example but it's not mentioning the user when someone joins, also had to edit the code a little cause of this https://prnt.sc/26qf9gm

Comment: Use [```member.mention```](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43964328/how-do-i-mention-a-user-in-discord-py)

Comment: My apologies @Flandead I had forgotten to add a ')' in the `random.choice` function. This can be seen in your error as well, the code has been fixed on that line.

Comment: @ChaoticNebula yes, that is in my answer already, and Flandead's traceback includes it. `discord.Member.mention` is the same as `member.mention` as `member` is a `discord.Member` object. Could you tell me where else this is needed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It was for @Flandead.

Comment: well, now I run into the problem that it doesn't mention anyone when they join

Comment: @Flandead do you receive any other errors?

Comment: none, it just doesn't do anything

Comment: Have you enabled intents?

Comment: I'm kinda new to all this discord bot thing, how do I enable them?

Comment: @Flandead have a look at this question [on_member_join not working, no error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64147556/discord-py-on-member-join-not-working-no-error-message) as it answers this question.

Comment: thanks, I wil try this as soon as I can

Comment: thanks, to all that commented trying to help. I can confirm that it works now