# Discord Member Join

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm creating a bot that when entering the server appears in a specific channel the name of the user who entered together with a message

I researched and made this code below but the same when I ran it didn't work and no error appeared, could you help me?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Member(commands.Cog):
def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_join(self, member):
    try:
        channel = self.bot.get_channel(Channel_ID)
        try:
            embed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour.green())
            embed.set_author(name=member.name, icon_url=member.avatar_url)
            embed.add_field(name="Welcome" ,value=f"**Hey,{member.mention}! Welcome to {member.guild.name}\nI hope you enjoy your stay here!\nThanks for joining**", inline=False)
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.guild.icon_url)
            await channel.send(embed=embed)
        except Exception as e:
            raise e
    except Exception as e:
        raise e

def setup(bot):
bot.add_cog(Member(bot))
```

Comment: I don't have a definite answer right now, but one of the two try-catch blocks you have is completely redundant and is not needed. I would suggest you remove the inner one, even if it is just for readability

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py on\_member\_join not working, no error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64147556/discord-py-on-member-join-not-working-no-error-message)

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was going wrong in my code, python was not recognizing the "`on_member_join`" function and for it to work I needed to add this command

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot("!", intents=intents)
```

I added the same in the file that I run the bot, I did the test and it worked